# Java How to use an array in a switch method

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I'm trying to learn Java and I'm working on my project "Collection of programs" // very simple ones: like a basic calculator, factorials, reversing numbers etc.
These programs are divided into categories like Mathematics, Drawings ... 
The problem is that maybe in the future I will want to have more categories/programs in it. 
I want to use arrays so I don't have to re-write my code every time I add a new program/category.

---

I have created an array of strings and updated my method welcomeUser.
But I don't know how to deal with my chooseBlock method and switch. 
**I would like to have as many cases as blocks in my Array.**

Thank you very much for every help

---

```
public class Program {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    private boolean programRunning = true;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Welcome in my program! (version 1.0.0)");
        while (programRunning) {
            welcomeUser();
            chooseBlock();
        }

    }

    public void welcomeUser() {
        System.out.println("You can choose from these blocks:\n"
                + "[1.Mathematic Block]\t"
                + "[2.Drawing block]\t"
                + "[3.Else...]\t"
                + "[4.Exit]\n"
                + "Select with a number and press ENTER");
    }

    public void chooseBlock() {
        int block = 0;
        block = scan.nextInt();
        switch (block) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("You've choosen Mathematic Block");
                Mathematics maths= new Mathematics();
                maths.run();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("You've choosen Drawing block");
                Drawings drawings = new Drawings();
                drawings.run();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("You've choosen Else block");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Exiting the program");
                programRunning = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

---

```
private String[] blocks
        = {"Mathematic Block", "Drawing Block", "Else", "Exit"};

public void welcomeUser() {

   System.out.println("You can choose from these blocks:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("[" + (i + 1) + ". " + blocks[i] + " ]\t");
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
   }
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Select with a number and press ENTER");
}
```

Comment: Your problem is a design problem. I.e. how to make this app easy to extend. That's a difficult problem, usually not for beginners. Moreover, there is more than one good answer for this kind of problems.
I suggest to keep your code as simple as possible. This makes things easy later on. No need to use `Arrays` when you don't need them right now. **When** you want to add another category, then you can ask a question about **that**.

Comment: The short answer, you want to use something like the strategy pattern. Each category will have it own strategy implementation. When you need to add a new category, you implement a new strategy. Know, instead of a `switch` you just have to get the instance of `Strategy` that is store in an array, the index will match the array of category. Simple and evolutive. But the first implementation take time since you need to have a strategy well defined. Strategy or State pattern are two similar, I might mix those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want easy extensibility of categories. There are many ways to achieve this. I'll sketch one approach for starters.

First of all I'd explicitly model categories in a class like `Category`:

```
public abstract class Category {
    public abstract String getTitle();
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Each of the specific categories will have its own class, extending `Category`

```
public class Mathematics extends Category {
    public String getTitle() { return "Mathematic Block";}
    public void run() { ... }
}
```

Then you'll have a list of availabe categories:

```
private List<Category> categories = Arrays.asList(new Mathematics(), ...);
```

Now you can display the list of available categories as follows:

```
public void welcomeUser() {
    System.out.println("You can choose from these blocks:");
    for (int index = 0; index < categories.size(); index++) { 
        Category category = categories.get(index);
        System.out.println("[" + (index+1) + "." + category.getTitle() + "]");
    }
    // ...
}
```

And instead of switch you can do:

```
int block = scan.nextInt();
int selectedCategoryIndex = block - 1;
if (selectedCategoryIndex >= 0 && selectedCategoryIndex < categories.size()) {
    Category selectedCategory = categories.get(selectedCategoryIndex);
    selectedCategory.run();
}
```

If there's a new category, just add it to `categories`.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm going to try it.

Comment: @user9635657 If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).